# How can I prevent interpretation of \u in the replace string

Tags: visual-studio-code, regexp-replace

I want to search for \u00FC and replace it with \u00fc

My search regex is: \u([0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]) and works fine

The replacement \L$1 does lowercase my 4 characters

However, I cannot find a way to write \u (I think vscode wants it to mean uppercase)

[image]

Comment: AFAICT the replacement text should be `\\u\L$1` but that also doesn't work, contary to e.g. `\\x\L$1`. Huh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by using a positive look behind:

In search bar:

Search: `(?<=\\u)((?:[0-9A-F]{4}))`

Replace: `\L$1`

---

The `\\u\L$1` works in the Find Replace dialog (`Ctrl+F`)

You can file a bug in the VSC repo

Comment: wow! ... I knew I had to ask :)